# Cartesian Coordinate system and straight lines

Tags: coordinate-systems

It's just a random doubt that came to my mind but it has really got me confused.

If we say that a straight line makes an angle, say 60 degrees, with the negative direction of the *X axis*, then does it mean taking the angle **from** the negative direction of *X axis* **to** the *straight line* in the anticlockwise direction or **from** the *straight line* **to** the negative direction of *X axis* anticlockwise. Similar goes for other directions of x and y axis. I know it has to be in the anticlockwise direction. But can you help me in which of the ways it has to be taken that I  mentioned above? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means the first one. 
While we say line A makes an angle with line B, we take the angle from B to A.

Comment: You also mean in anticlockwise direction, right?

Comment: And also saying this means that making an angle with positive or negative X is equivalent, because the vertically opposite angles will be equal?

Comment: @SaumilSood Yes